# Translate powermail form

Tags: fluid, typo3-10.x, powermail

I wonder what is the easiest way to translate a powermail form into multiple languages (approx. 10 languages, for this example let's just use English (default) and translate into German).

What have i done so far:

- installed powermail through composer
- created a form with 5 fields.
- added that form to a page.
- saving form to database.

What i need is a way to translate this form into German, but i have no idea where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was trying to accomplish. Thought I would share it here since I haven't found an acceptable answer online yet.

To translate your form open the page where your form is located in Listview.
[image]

After you made a new translation for your page, there is an extra option in your form to localize it to another language:
[image]

Click on the countryflag and you are able to translate your form!